# ErrorDocument only when referer is empty

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-referer, errordocument

I want to add in my .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php (etc) but only when the referer is empty.
So, if an user wrongly typed an URL, gets the error-404.php, but when I linked an image in my page and doesnt exists, the default error 404 apears.

That way, I save bandwidth not downloading HTML+CSS+stuff when the user wont see the Error.

But i dont know how to do it :(

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule !error-404.php /error-404.php [L]
```

Don't set `ErrorDocument` to the php file, otherwise your default 404 won't ever appear. Note that this won't return a 404 code by default, your `error-404.php` needs to do this by using something like [the header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).